# Why does get the error for ambiguous redirect here?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to listen to a pipe and wrote this code, but I get the ambiguous redirect error, why that?

```
pipe = "./$1"

# trap enables to execute a command when a signal is sent to your script
trap "rm -f $pipe" EXIT


if [[ ! -p $pipe ]]; then
    mkfifo $pipe
fi


while true
do
    if read line <$pipe; then
        if ["$line" == 'EXIT'  -o  "$line" == 'exit' ]; then
            break
        else 
            echo $line
        fi
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect your first line fails with the error:

> pipe: command not found

Because variable assignment in `bash` does not support whitespace between the variable name and the `=` sign. Therefore, `$pipe` is left undefined and `read line < $pipe` fails. Try:

```
pipe="./$1"
```